# XamlParseException when using FontIcon from resources in Universal App

Tags: windows-phone, appbar, win-universal-app

I am trying to put FontIcons for buttons I am using in my appbar in resources. The code is the following:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <FontFamily x:Key="IconsFont">/Assets/iconfont.ttf#iconfont</FontFamily>
    <FontIcon x:Key="LogoutIcon" FontFamily="{StaticResource IconsFont}" Glyph="&#xe600;" FontSize="35" />
  </Page.Resources>
<Page.BottomAppBar>
  <CommandBar>
    <AppBarButton Icon="Find" Label="search" Command="{Binding SearchCommand}" Visibility="{Binding SearchCommandVisibility}"/>
    <AppBarButton Label="logout" Command="{Binding LogoutCommand}" Icon="{StaticResource LogoutIcon}" />
  </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

In designer it all looks fine, the icon is displayed correctly. But when I launch the app I am getting XamlParseException with generic error text: "Failed to assign to property '%0'"

If I take the FontIcon out of resources it also works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Find" Label="search"/>
        <AppBarButton Label="logout">
            <AppBarButton.Icon>
                <FontIcon FontFamily="{StaticResource IconsFont}" Glyph="&#xe600;" FontSize="35"/>
            </AppBarButton.Icon>
        </AppBarButton>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

And remove `<FontIcon x:Key="LogoutIcon" FontFamily="{StaticResource IconsFont}" Glyph="&#xe600;" FontSize="35" />` from page resource.

Comment: This works, but it is not what I need. I need to keep the icon in resources.